# Why do PDFs generated from HTML with images consume significantly more storage than the images themselves?

Tags: html, image, pdf

EDIT: The malfunction in Chromium was caused by a bug, which has since been fixed. Thank you to everyone who contributed to finding the solution!

Why do PDFs generated from HTML with images consume significantly more storage than the images themselves, and how can I avoid this?

E.g.

This image have ~1.6MB
https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/21/63/kGOzq7.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Example</title>
        <style>
            body {
                position: relative;
                width: 148mm;
                height: 210mm;
                margin: 0;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
                border: 1px dashed black;
                user-select: none;
            }
            div.textarea {
                position: relative;
                flex-grow: 1;
                margin: 12mm 15mm 20mm 15mm;
            }
            img {
                width: 100%;
            }
            @media print {
                @page {
                    size: A5;
                    margin: 0;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="textarea odd">
            <img src="https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/21/63/kGOzq7.jpg" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please take a look at this html file. It includes the image I posted before. If I print this html in a pdf file by chrom(ium), the pdf file is 5,3MB but the image has only a size of 1.6MB.

Why is it so much higher?

Comment: Note that the opposite can also happen. Convert your image with [this online converter](https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/online/jpg-to-pdf.html) and the resulting file is less than 400 KB big. Almost any file size is possible, depending on how you generate it. Is this important to you? Why?

Comment: @KJ Thank you for your in-depth analysis of what's happening to the image. In the end the size of the resulting PDF depends on how the image is processed, and there are many ways you can do this. What we do _not know_ is why Barock asked this question. What is the process in which the size of the resulting PDF is important? One thing is certain, the size, when using "print" in Chrome, will always be the same. Would Barock be able, or willing, to use another method?

Comment: It seems to be a progressive JPEG. Progressive JPEGs are only allowed in PDF version 1.3 and above, so perhaps the print-to-PDF functionality of the browser was written before that time, and automatically re-encodes progressive JPEGs in a lossless way. If it's not that, something else about this JPEG is flagging it for reprocessing anyway. Safari also produces a 5.6Mb PDF, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had been an open Chromium issue from way back (at least a decade) see https://issues.chromium.org/issues/41132531, still open. Many different bug reports but based on false assumptions such as "JPEGs are converted to PNG, resulting PDF is huge, no quality of images is gained from this". This is totally wrong, as there cannot be a PNG internally in a PDF (PDF design predated PNG introduction). PNG is imported to PDF as 1 or 2 bitmap images one the RGB/CMYK colours and the optional alpha SoftMask image.

It boils down to Chrome  using Skia appears to use only a single "codec" output dependency from libjpeg-turbo as "Flatted" compression (for all image types). Mozilla Browsers may use Cairo to generate PDF. However they may **also provide similar inflation by a different amount 4.91 MB** in this case !

Images such as specifically JPEG should not alter in size / content (Thus no change in "quality") when embedded in HTML. The only change that may be needed is convert to dataURL due to CORS thus 134% larger as text.

When a "baseline" JPEG image container is wrapped by insert into a PDF page it **should** retain all its metadata without altering image rotation or native density.

### Edit

I tried to explain a reason but let's just simplify it as a mis-coding in Chrome.

### Answer

It should not be a problem in version 122 and onwards. If it happens again then try the following.

Use MS Edge or other JPEG efficient Chromium browser such as Opera. Not mainstream Chrome. Side by side comparison of output size. Image source (lowest entry) is 1,640,352 bytes. MS Edge output is 1611 KB and same function in Chrome is 5625 KB as its flatted Google Web format.

[image]

MS Edge stores the pure image as /Length `1640352` as does Opera

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This bug seems to have been fixed since one of the last version updates.

Answer (score 1):

Generating a pdf from the provided image in firefox seems to give the same result with 5.7 MiB, and looking at the hexdump reveals a possible cause:

[image: hexdump of the pdf, showing the image is encoded]

The PDF standard might include its own image encoding scheme, which the browser needs to convert to before embedding the image. This might make the image several times larger in size, since it's no longer in the same file format. You can confirm this isn't a JPG anymore, since the header should usually start with `ff d8 ff e0 ...` followed by "JFIF", which is nowhere to be found in this case.

Comment: You're implying that "the PDF standard" causes the file to get so big. This is not true. It's the choices made by the conversion tool used, in this case a printer driver that generates a PDF file. But you're right that the PDF often doesn't contain an exact copy, byte for byte, of the original JPG file.